# apache 2.2 to 2.4 sporadic performance drop

Tags: php, performance, apache

I updated apache from 2.2 to 2.4 and php from 5.3 to 5.4.
For some reason I am experiencing huge performance drops in around 5% of requests to the server. On average, sites load in less than 2 seconds but in this 5% of cases it takes anywhere between 30 to 60 seconds of spinning before the site finally loads.

I copied my old prefork settings

```
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   10
ServerLimit      512
MaxClients       512
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000:
```

Setup: 8 vCPU, 8gb ram, SSD
CPU never goes over 30%, ram stays at around 1.8GB.

DB is on a separate server and performs very fast. I already debugged it and never got a slow query (nothing over a minute).

I already performed 2.2 to 2.4 update steps from here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html
but it didnt help. Is there any other way to debug the server and why it slows down so badly? 
I do not suspect the php to be the reason since the codebase did not change.

EDIT

I need to add that when the page is spnning, i can click on the link, press enter and there is a big chnage that it will load in under 2 seconds. Sometimes I have to hit enter or refresh this loading page 2 or 3 times and it loads immediately.

Comment: Shouldn't that question be in Server Fault community? It's seems totally related to Apache web server configuration... By the way, how are your cache settings?

Comment: Cache is handled by google pagespeed (caching images, js, css ect) with its core filters